# Auto Incrementing Serial Number in a datagridview starting like 1.0,1.2.....1.9,2.0.2.1 etc in vb.net application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagrid

In my VB.Net Application one of my form has a `DataGridView` and I would like to auto generate serial numbers with this sequence : 1.0, 1.1, .... 1.9, 2.0, 2.1 etc
These values will be generated at run time and are not stored into a database.

I am planning to input values through the `DataGridView`.

Comment: I would delete by 10

Comment: I think @venimus meant divide by 10...

Comment: yeah, divide. sorry :D lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to generate such a sequence using SQL, you need a Numbers table.

You can generate such a table manually like this

```
;WITH Numbers as 
(SELECT 1 rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), N2 as 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY rn) - 1 as N
FROM Numbers
)
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(1),T1.N) + '.' + CONVERT(CHAR(1),T2.N) as seq
FROM N2 T1 CROSS JOIN N2 T2
WHERE T1.N >= 1
ORDER BY T1.N,T2.N
```